# commutator of operator function with spectral theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

I want to show that for self-adjoint operators $A$ and $B$ which satisfy $[A,B]=i\mathbb{I}$ and $F(\mathsf{\xi})$ continously differentiable, $\mathsf{\xi} \in \mathbb{R}$, $$[A,F(B)]=i\frac{dF(B)}{dB}$$ holds. I tried to use spectral theorem (over which these operator functions can be defined) as follows, but don't know how to continue: $$[A,F(B)]=\textstyle \sum_i F(b_\text {i})[A, \left| b_\text {i} \right\rangle \left\langle b_\text {i} \right|].$$ Here $b_\text {i}$ are the eigenvalues of $B$ and $\left| b_\text {i} \right\rangle$ the eigenvectors. How does the differentiation emerge? I succeed to show it for polynomial operator functions.

Comment: How do you define $F(B)$?

Comment: It is way more simple.

Comment: $F(B):=\textstyle \sum_i F(b_\text {i}) P_\text {i}$, where $P_\text {i}$ is the projection onto eigenvectors.

Comment: This is a homework question.

Comment: The definition you should be using is $F(B)=\sum_n \frac{1}{n!}c_{n} B^n$, where $c_n=\left.(\partial^n F/\partial B^n)\right|_{B=0}$ are expansion coefficients which define the formal power series.

Comment: But when $B$ is not restricted, wouldn't the domain for the powers of $B$ shrink? I think $F$ doesn't need to have a power series.

Comment: I mean what if $B$ is a differential operator, which is not restricted in general?